# Laravel match ID across multiple tables

Tags: laravel, routes

I am using a 16 character alphanumeric string as IDs (MDBIDs) throughout my app; for users, artists, albums, tracks etc.

I am using `route::pattern` to match this.

**routes.php**

```
Route::pattern('mdbid', '[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}');

Route::get('/{mdbid}','MdbidsController@show');
```

**MdbidsController.php** (controller)

```
public function show($mdbid)
{
    //return $mdbid;
    return Mdbid::whereMdbid($mdbid)->first()->table();
}
```

**Mdbid.php** (model)

```
public function table() {
    return $this->table_name;
}
public function show($mdbid)
{
    switch($table_name) {
        case 'artists':

            break;
    }
    //$album = Album::findOrFail($id);
    $album = Album::whereMdbid($mdbid)->firstOrFail();

    return View::make(table().'show', compact('album'));
}
```

I would like to know how I can find which table the **MDBID** belongs to and then call the show method on that model.

I am thinking that it would be ok to have a `show` method on the `IdsController` that returns the relevant view but I am stuck as to how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has any issues with this, then please do say. However, this is the solution that I have some up with and it works.

**MdbidsController.php**

```
public function show($mdbid)
{
    try {
        $table = Mdbid::whereMdbid($mdbid)->firstOrFail()->table();
    } catch ( ModelNotFoundException $e ) {
        Notification::error("Sorry that MDBID doesn't exist.");
        return Redirect::home();
    }
    switch ($table) {
        case 1:
            $artist = Artist::whereMdbid($mdbid)->firstOrFail();
            return Redirect::to('artists/' . $artist->mdbid);
            break;
        case 2:
            $album = Album::whereMdbid($mdbid)->firstOrFail();
            return Redirect::to('albums/' . $album->mdbid);
            break;
        case 3:
            $track = Track::whereMdbid($mdbid)->firstOrFail();
            return Redirect::to('tracks/' . $track->mdbid);
            break;
        case 7:
            $user = User::whereMdbid($mdbid)->firstOrFail();
            return Redirect::to('users/' . $user->mdbid);
            break;
        case 8:
            $tag = Tag::whereMdbid($mdbid)->firstOrFail();
            return Redirect::to('tags/' . $tag->mdbid);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh right, so you pretty much do have a polymorphic relationship here. From the looks of it you have a central table (Mdbids) that stores the MDBID and the table it refers to, and then from that you actually query the relevant table for the MDBID. I guess if your solution works then you're all good really. Polymorphic would certainly work here but probably not really help too much - you're pretty much doing the job of the polymorphic relation with your own code.

Comment: There I was thinking that I am hacking it together. :)

Comment: @alexrussell how do I insert into the MDBID table when I create a user, artist, album etc?

Comment: I suppose there are a few ways, but the most sensible maybe would be to hook into the `creating` event for the three models - get the ID and then insert into MDBID. It isn't atomic, so if you need it to be you'll have to not hook into the `creating` event but instead do it manually whenever you create a row with a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good use-case for polymorphic relationships - you have one table that stores all the MDBIDs, and that table links out to artists, albums, etc.

Check out [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations).

Comment: I have sorted it with a simple switch statement, however I don't know if that is the best way to go about it.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much the models interrelate. I suppose if it's just that the MDBIDs happen to look the same, but otherwise aren't different types of the same supertype, then polymorphic relationships aren't what you want. So maybe what you have will work the best, though I'm curious as to how you've implemented it with a `switch` - I'd have thought a `if ($model = Artist::find()) {} else if ($model = Album::find()) {}` would be most sensible here.

Comment: As you are kinda alluding to, handling different types of resource form one URL pattern is asking for trouble when it comes to the structure of a framework with controllers and views, etc.

Comment: I will look into polymorphic relationships. I think for now the solution I have will work. But I will consider it in the future. Thank you.

Comment: I have added my own solution. This may better explain what I was trying to accomplish. Please do tell me if I am heading down the wrong path.